# Scheduled task sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

Exist a way to run a Scheduled task, on sharepoint 2013 online? I have created a sharepoint hosted app, but I don't know how to wake up this app every minute or hour...

Comment: you can write script and shedule it on your PC...warmup script hit the page/app you want to bring back...

Comment: How about app-only permission and `TokenHelper`? Ref http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2014/03/02/building-a-sharepoint-app-as-a-timer-job.aspx